# Command line to start visual studio and disable add ins/Extensions for that instance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, command-line, add-in

I am writing a Visual Studio template wizard.  And to debug it I have it start a new instance of Visual Studio 2010.

My Visual Studio 2010 takes a good while to start up.  I believe that this is due the the add-ins and extensions that I have installed for visual studio.

I would rather not go disable them all (I really like them).  So I was hoping there was a way to disable them via the command line.

Just run a clean Visual Studio instance.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try safemode

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

which

> Starts Visual Studio in safe mode, and loads only the default environment and services, and shipped versions of third-party packages.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx

Comment: In my case, devenv.exe was located in the `Common7\IDE` folder in my Visual Studio installation. E.g. for Visual Studio 2015: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`