# Visual studio 2012 wont start

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I installed VS2012 Premium from our MSDN subscription and 
it was working fine the first couple of days but then I installed a few extensions 
but now VS2012 does not start  and it gives the error:

```
    Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 
    0x5011ecaa        
    Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
    Exception code: 0xc000041d
    Fault offset: 0x77cc11f1
    Faulting process id: 0x12c0
    Faulting application start time: 0x01cf525c0d374f44
    Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
    11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe         
    Faulting module path: unknown
    Report Id: 4cd88dc0-be4f-11e3-bf75-0023245b4b3a
```

I'm running it on Windows 7 64 bit.I tried to repair \ Uninstall and install again.But it doesnt work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655732/command-line-to-start-visual-studio-and-disable-add-ins-extensions-for-that-inst

Comment: Remove the extensions. You should be able to search for this and find how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to to run devenv.exe with the /SafeMode

Also check [VS 2012 will not start](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d848776a-b00f-4311-ab09-3a8777462968/vs-2012-will-not-start?forum=vssetup):

> I had similar issue, you may be in the same boat.Found this from
>   somebody else when looking around.
>
> The problem is with VS2012 Commands extension. It puts the registry
>   entry below that somehow causes the ntdll error. What I did was take
>   out the whole Layers key, start VS2012 and remove the extension. You
>   may have to do it twice if VS manages to put it back when you start
>   the first time.
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers] "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"=""

So you follow the instruction from above:

1. Removed the key: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]`. VS2012 loading but then crashing before I could do anything else (error in `C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll`)
2. Then remove:

   - `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0]`
   - `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config]`
     and start again.

Comment: I take out whole layers key ,start VS2012 , nut still it gives above error message.Value of below key on my machine as follow                     
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows         NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers] "C:\Program Files     (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"="DISABLEUSERCALLBACKEXCEPTION"  Also,there is no key-value exists on my machine for this
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0]
And , this registery not exists on my machine
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config]